# Fatal error with CI result() method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I get an undefined method when I call the `result()` method of CodeIgniter. I have used this method before in another program and it has worked fine but I don't know why it is not working now. I have read up and never has it said that I need to load any libraries and I never done so in my other program so I can't work out why it doesn't know what method it is.

The error I get is the following:

```
[20-Dec-2013 14:57:23 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::result() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CI/application/controllers/mainController.php on line 34
```

Here is my controller code:

```
class mainController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mainModel');
    }
    public function index() {
       $this->load->view('homePage');
    }
    public function chngView(){
       $this->load->view('mainView');
    }
    public function search() {
        $value = $this->input->get('id');
        $details = $this->mainModel->search($value);
        $result = $details->result();
        $this->load->view('mainView', array('values' => $result));
    }
}
```

Heres my model:

```
class mainModel extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function search($value){
        $data = $this->db->like($value);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Lastly my view:

```
<html>
    <form action="/CI/index.php/mainController/search" method='get'>
        <input type="text" value="Enter id" name="id">
        <input type="submit" value="enter">
    </form>
    <?php
      if (isset($values)) {
          foreach ($values as $row) {
              echo $row->title;
          }
      }
    ?>
</html>
```

So could someone tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function search($value){
    $data = $this->db->like($value);
    return $data;
}
```

Here is problem.You are forgeting to call `get` which runs the query. You query has not been run so you cant use `result()`. Remember the `result()` can only be used after `get`.

Use this instead

```
public function search($value){
    $data = $this->db->like($value)->get('tablename');
    return $data;
}
```